# Female robot/android self aware movie, unreleased as of 2016-06-15

Tags: story-identification

I was trying to recall/search for the name of a new movie about a female robot/android that has become self aware. I saw the trailer in theater. The movie properly is not out yet as of today(2016-06-15).

Things I remember from trailer:

1. Futuristic world
2. Android/Robot are common on the street, but they are tools/servants only
3. The trailer picture the main character walking on the street, and there is something like a bus stop
4. The story seems to be about this female robot/android trying to hide the fact that she has gain self awareness while living in the human world.

I know it is not the following:

- The Machine
- Ex Machina

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you talking about [Detroit: Become Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit:_Become_Human)? It's a game, not a movie, but it matches every detail you mentioned.

From Wikipedia:

> Kara (Valorie Curry) is a freshly-produced android with artificial
>   consciousness who is discovering how it is to live among humans. She
>   struggles to find her place as an autonomous android, in a world where
>   androids are still without consciousness and considered practical
>   tools to improve the comfort of humans.

Comment: OMG!!! Yes, that's why I cannot find it, I was looking in the wrong category! Thank you very very much!!!!